# How to edit NSAttributedstring background color size and position with Swift

Tags: swift, fonts, background, nsattributedstring, truetype

in my app I have a feature where user can add background color to text

So, I added .backgroundColor attribute and it works but background position is different for different fonts. Is there a way to edit string background size and position or should I try to edit ttf fonts instead?

Thanks

Edit - Code:

I tried 2 methods
First one excluding spaces:

```
var startIndex = self.text.startIndex
while let r = self.text.range(of: "\\S+", options: .regularExpression, range: startIndex..<self.text.endIndex) {
   customizedText.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: highlightColor, range: NSRange(r, in: self.text))
                startIndex = r.upperBound
}
```

[Result excluding spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4d05.jpg)

Another one is simply add background color for every char:

```
customizedText.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: highlightColor, range: range)
```

[Result: whole string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tdik.jpg)

Ass you can see, it's doesn't look good with any alignment but Left.

We could probably live with this but problem is what it looks horribly wrong with some other fonts

Examples:

[Gayatri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puuAU.jpg) [Anton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoCTn.jpg)

Another example of what is now(red) and what I want(white):
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb5t3.jpg)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots, show your current result and your expectation? And your code as well please

Comment: Added details: code and expected result